# How to make a layout adaptive to screen zoom in-out levels

Tags: javascript, html, css

the below posted `.css` file, is for a pop-up menu that appears on mouse-click.
the problem i have is, as shown in image `img-1`, it illustrates the appearance of the pop-up menu at specific zoom of the screen. when the user presses `ctrl + -` it causes the screen to zoom out, then i got a popup menu as shown in `img-2`

my question is, how to avoid deformation of the contents of the pop-up menu regardless to the screen zoom lever `ctrl + +` or `ctrl + -`

i want the contents to adapt itself according to the screen zoom level please.

**img-1**:

[image]

**img-2**:

[image]

**.html**:

```
<div id="idGridCellInfoPopupDiv" class="ol-popup">
<div id="idCloseButtonX" class="closeButtonX">
    <button
        aria-label="Close"
        class="close"
        type="button"
        (click)="setPopupOverlayInvisible()"
        enabled >
        <clr-icon aria-hidden="true" shape="close"></clr-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<div id="idAlertDiv" class="alert alert-success alert-sm" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-items">
        <div class="alert-item static">
            <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
                <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="check-circle"></clr-icon>
            </div>
            <div id="idAlertTextGridCellInfoMousePosValueDiv"class="alert-text">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="header-nav">
    <button 
        id="idGridCellInfoTab" 
        class="nav-link nav-text" 
        (click)="onGridCellInfoTabClicked()"
        [disabled]="isGridCellInfoTabDisabled" >
        {{ "SITE.POPUP_OVERLAY.GRID_CELL_INFO_LABEL" | translate }}
    </button>

    <button id="idRiskTab" 
        class="nav-link nav-text" 
        (click)="onRiskTabClicked()"
        [disabled]="isRiskTabDisabled" >
        {{ "SITE.POPUP_OVERLAY.RISK_LABEL" | translate }}
    </button>
        
</div>

<div *ngIf="showContentsOfGridCellInfoTab" id="idContentsOfGridCellInfoTab">
    <div id="idGridCellInfoZoneDiv">{{Zone}}</div>
    <div id="idGridCellInfoAoCValueDiv">{{AoC}}</div>
    <div id="idGridCellInfoAvgHValueDiv">{{AvgH}}</div>
    <div id="idGridCellInfoDistValueDiv">{{Dist}}</div>
    <div id="idGridCellInfoIValueDiv">{{I}}</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="showContentsOfRiskTab" id="idContentsOfRiskTab">
    <div id="idETRValueDiv">{{ETRValue}}</div>
    <div id="idETRCategoryDiv">{{ETRCategory}}</div>
</div>
```

**.css**:

```
.ol-popup {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 27px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  bottom: 161px;
  left: -49px;
  top: -53px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 169px;
  margin-top: -120px;
  }
.ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
  top: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.ol-popup:after {
  border-top-color: white;
  border-width: 10px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.ol-popup:before {
  border-top-color: #cccccc;
  border-width: 11px;
  left: 48px;
  margin-left: -11px;
}
.ol-popup-closer {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: 2px;
}
.ol-popup-closer:after {
  content: "✖";
}
.alert-sm .alert-text {
  margin-right: -4.75rem;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
#idCloseButtonX{
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right:-8px;
  background: transparent;
}
.custom-mouse-position{
  margin-top: 2px; 
}
#idAlertDiv{
  margin-top: 2px;
  right: 1px;
  width: 239px;
}

#idGridCellInfoTab{
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 115px;
}
#idRiskTab{
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: 119px;
  width: 115px;
}

#idETRValueDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#idETRCategoryDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  left: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#idAlertTextGridCellInfoMousePosValueDiv{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: -27px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
#idContentsOfGridCellInfoTab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
}

#idGridCellInfoZoneDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#idGridCellInfoAoCValueDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: max-content;
}
#idGridCellInfoAvgHValueDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  width: max-content;
}
#idGridCellInfoDistValueDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: max-content;
}
#idGridCellInfoIValueDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: The HTML is missing from your question, which makes your CSS meaningless.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i added the .html please have a look

Comment: Thank you, but that's not only HTML. Anyway, it is clear to me that you use `position: absolute;` way to many times. That's not how modern websites are written. Media queries alone will not solve this, it will just make it even more unwieldy. It is clear you need to learn more about how to write a website, but this is not the platform to teach you that.

Comment: @Yogi Do you mean the popup close button pushing other content down?: Yes please

Comment: @Yogi what kind of flaws the popup has please? i am not a profissional in  html ans css

Comment: You can find good code for modal popups online. For instance [here](https://www.codexworld.com/simple-modal-popup-javascript-css/) and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/4-ways-to-create-a-modal-popup-box-with-html-css-a). Check out how they do it, learn for it, and adapt it to your situation. The reason the content of your popup moves, when zooming, is that you mix various [absolute and relative length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Answer (score 0):

It reacts the same way as if your resolution would change, so the only thing you can do is use media queries.

Given your original `.ol-popup` has `width: 280px;`, then with media queries, you would either increase or decrease that width based on the device screen width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .ol-popup {
    width: 80px;
  }
}
```

or

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .ol-popup {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

Media queries basically read the screen resolution to give you flexibility to modify your website's layout.

These are core building blocks of the [responsive design paradigm](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp), and you can implement the same media queries for any element.

I would also suggest expressing widths in percentages (like `width: 80%`, `50%`), or viewport heights/widths (`width: 70vw`).

Comment: hi, what is media queries please? can ypu provide an example please?

Comment: hi, of course, I will update my original answer